# PW Script to compress files

Tags: powershell, zip

I have the following script that does the following :

```
$sourceFiles = "c:\Documents\Reports\20200708reports"

$destinationFolder = "c:\Documents\Reports\20200708reports.zip"

If(Test-path $destinationFolder) {Remove-item $destinationFolder}

Add-Type -assembly "system.io.compression.filesystem"

[io.compression.zipfile]::CreateFromDirectory($SourceFiles, $destinationFolder)
```

Script is not working a 100 % correctly

Goal is to compress/zip everything and if possible add Today's Date as the name of the zip, instead of inputting  it manually every day

Thanks, plan is to add a schedule task to run it daily. Folder is getting a bit heavy

Comment: `$destinationFolder = "c:\Documents\Reports\$(get-date -Format 'yyyyMMdd')reports.zip"`

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

```
$sourceFiles = "c:\Documents\Reports\20200708reports"
$destinationFolder = "c:\Documents\Reports\$(GET-DATE -Format "yyyyMMdd")reports.zip"

Compress-Archive -Path $sourceFiles  -CompressionLevel Optimal -DestinationPath $destinationFolder -Force
```